# Firebase Deploy apresenta mensagem por estar 'aguardando APIs' para habilitar

Tags: angularjs, aplicação-web, firebase, google, deploy

Fala galera, tô fazendo meu primeiro deploy no Firebase, e me deparei com essa lindeza.

Infelizmente não encontrei nada nas interwebs sobre, e recorro como sempre aos senhores, existe algo que eu possa fazer para solucionar tal problema?

```
i  deploying database, storage, firestore, functions, hosting
i  database: checking rules syntax...
+  database: rules syntax is valid
i  storage: checking storage.rules for compilation errors...
+  storage: rules file storage.rules compiled successfully
i  firestore: checking firestore.rules for compilation errors...
+  firestore: rules file firestore.rules compiled successfully
i  functions: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
i  runtimeconfig: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
+  runtimeconfig: all necessary APIs are enabled
!  functions: missing necessary APIs. Enabling now...
i  functions: waiting for APIs to activate...
i  functions: waiting for APIs to activate...

Error: Timed out waiting for APIs to enable. Please try again in a few minutes.
```

Imagino que tenha uma chance razoável de que não haja o que fazer, aparentemente era pro Google ter APIs infinitas ou algo assim... mas... se alguém souber como solucionar esse BO, fico agradecido.

Answer (score 0):

Encontrei uma solução,

ao invés de 'firebase deploy' eu usei 'firebase deploy --only hosting'

Existe uma issue aberta, e caso eu veja alguma resposta/atualização, faço update aqui. Mas por hora o comando diferente já 'resolve'.